# Excel Power Query Editor save file

Tags: excel, powerquery

Is it possible to save an Excel file while working in Power Query Editor (without closing the Editor)?  I am using <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> regularly as I work in Power Query Editor to save progress, but if Excel crashes and I go to re-open the file, it turns out that the file has not been saved at all!

Have had this happen to me several times now with hours of work wasted!

Comment: @DavideBacci  Thank you for taking time to read and reply to my question.  As stated, I was looking for a solution to save the file without having to close the Editor, but it sounds like this isn't possible.  So I will probably need to close the question as unresolved (if there is such an option?)

Comment: I understand. The answer should be marked as solved though (feel free to pick any answer). It is an answer to your question (the answer being that there is no exact solution) rather than a solution to your problem. If someone else asks the same question, they will see the question you posed and know the options available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close and load and then save (close & load to just connection in order to save just the query rather than loads lots of data). PQ saving is a bit annoying as there is no undo either so make frequent use of duplicate query when testing new logic or save and load so you can revert any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just go into home ... advanced editor ... copy the code and paste it into notepad in case of crash while doing development